# On-screen keyboard for touchscreen app

Tags: cocoa, macos, touchscreen

I am developing a kiosk-style application that is going to be used with a touchscreen. Are there any simple, well-written on-screen keyboards for Cocoa? Note that this *is not* for an iPhone app, but rather targetting OS X 10.5/10.6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the one that comes with OS X is pretty nice. Check out Keyboard -> Show Keyboard & Character Viewer in System Preferences, then go to the new icon in the menu bar and select 'Show Keyboard Viewer'

Comment: You can't hold down modifier keys with that one, though, so capital letters, accented letters, symbols, and most punctuation characters are inaccessible. That may be good enough—it depends on what the questioner's users will need to type.

Comment: I need to be able to programmatically control it. That is, I don't want it to be visible all the time. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [opening onscreen keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673965/opening-onscreen-keyboard/2675571#2675571) question.