# opening onscreen keyboard

Tags: cocoa

How can i open Keyboard viewer which is inbuilt in all Mac OS X from my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 10.5 and earlier here's the path to it so just launch it like normal:

```
/System/Library/Components/KeyboardViewer.component/Contents/SharedSupport/KeyboardViewerServer.app
```

On 10.6 and later that doesn't work. You'll need this: http://github.com/nriley/keyboardViewer

Comment: hi instead of calling by giving a path, i found this one. just call the launchapplication methods of nsworkspace giving the application name or the bundle identifier. 

[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchAppWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.KeyboardViewerServer"             options:NSWorkspaceLaunchAsync          additionalEventParamDescriptor:nil            launchIdentifier:nil];